# Bug in dash game with Rigidbody2D.Velocity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, velocity, rigid-bodies

So I am making a game in unity where an object will dash in the direction (unit vector) of the player's mouse click. Based on dash speed and dash time variables I made and set in the inspector it will usually work, as in the distance dashed by the object and its velocity are usually constant. However, sometimes the dash distance of the object will be off. I attempted to troubleshoot the problem by logging the dash distance and the object's velocity and what I found was that sometimes either or both variables with be some random value for some reason I am missing. On most clicks though the variables are the same number. Here is my code:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D))]
public class DashController : MonoBehaviour
{
Rigidbody2D rigidbody;
public float dashSpeed;
public float dashTime; //dash time for inspector use
float codeDashTime; //dash time for code use
bool dashing;
Vector2 direction;
Vector2 startPosition;
Vector2 endPosition;
float distance;

private void Start()
{
    rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    codeDashTime = dashTime;
    dashing = false;
}

private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        //need to subtract the current postion from the target postion
        direction = (Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - this.transform.localPosition);
        startPosition = this.transform.localPosition; // used to see the distance player dashes
        dashing = true;
    }

    if (dashing)
    {
        Dash();
    }
}

void Dash()
{
    if (codeDashTime > 0)
    {
        rigidbody.velocity = direction.normalized * dashSpeed;
        codeDashTime -= Time.deltaTime;
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log(rigidbody.velocity.magnitude);// used to see the velocity the player travels at
        Debug.Log(direction.normalized.magnitude);
        rigidbody.velocity = Vector2.zero;
        endPosition = this.transform.localPosition; // used to see the distance player dashes
        distance = Vector2.Distance(startPosition, endPosition);// used to see the distance player dashes
        Debug.Log(distance); // used to see the distance player dashes
        dashing = false;
        codeDashTime = dashTime;
    }
}
```

}

Sorry if my code is a bit jumbled. I have been moving things around a lot testing different solutions but nothing has worked. My best guess is that maybe something with the frames is messing up codeDashTime, but I am too new to unity and C# to know. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

All Physics should run on FixedUpdate and the inputs are normally used on Update, try separate them to get a better Rigidbody behaviour.

Comment: Oh wow. Thank you for the quick reply. Definitely will try this.

Comment: Bless you, that worked. Good advice to know too thanks.